# How to schedule a cronjob for a php file?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am working on Linux server and I have a group of php files each of them write to my database I write all the files directories in a bash file and I run this file manually using command line.
I want to make this automatically by using cronjob to run this file daily but I have two problems:

1.I should run the file 09:00GMT so I need to know what time does the cronjob work according to?Is it the server time? and if it is the server time how to know the server time region ?

2.how I could know the file directory exactly? I mean my file directory is: `public_html/codes/myfile.sh`
is it enough or I should write home/domainanem/.....

I am new on linux commands and cronjobs so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Times in crontabs are machine's local time. To get a GMT time in local's timezone, run: `date -d '9:00 GMT'`
2. You need to include absolute paths in your crontab. Run `readlink -f <relative_path_to_file>`. this will output the (real) absolute path of the file.